# Memory not being collected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory, garbage-collection

I'm working on an MDI style winforms app which loads images as the documents. One document can hold many images which are stored as Bitmap instances. I'm finding that when I close one of the documents, the GC isn't restoring the memory. So if I open and close a document a few times, the memory increases quite a lot. Especially as my app stores the image as 16 bits per channel, so images are very big. It actually runs out of memory after opening an closing a document a few times.

At first I thought I had a memory leak, but it turns out that when I close a document, if I call GC.Collect, then the memory is correctly collected, and my problem goes away.

Am I right in thinking that if GC.Collect is freeing up the memory, that means I don't have a leak? And is there a reason why the GC isn't doing this on it's own? Any reason not to use GC.Collect explicitly in this case?

Comment: Are you testing this in Debug or Release profiles?

Comment: Also do you have a debugger attached while you are testing this? the GC holds on to objects a LOT longer while a debugger is attached (otherwise the `Watch` window would fail half the time). Also are you Disposeing the Bitmap objects when you are done with them?

Comment: make sure you wrap your bitmaps / images with using clauses so that they are disposed properly. You need to be careful with bitmaps / images

Comment: It's in release mode, not run in the debugger. I did actually do a bit of testing in the debugger though - so that's a useful tip to remember - thanks

Comment: All my bitmaps are being freed. They can't all be in using statements, but I am using IDisposable in my Image class, and also keeping a reference count just to make sure.

Comment: Yep, it throws the System.OutOfMemoryException exception.

Comment: Have you checked if Dispose is being called?

Comment: Yep, it's definitely being called. It just seems to need an explicit GC.Collect to get the memory back.

Comment: Plain and simple, you are forgetting to dispose bitmaps.  The GC isn't running often enough to keep you out of trouble.

Comment: Let's suppose that your code disposes all resources, but as @HansPassant notes, the GC doesn't run often enough to prevent `System.OutOfMemoryException` for this particular 'stress' test. If this is possible with the GC then options are _(a)_ use `GC.Collect` for a quick & dirty 'fix', or _(b)_ use lazy loading: if "one document can hold many images" then maybe not all images are always needed; instantiate each `Bitmap` object as and when it should become visible. Documents should load faster too when designed for lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

1. if the memory gets collected then yes you do not have a memory leak.
2. you shouldn't use explicitly call to GC.Collect because it can be heavy on performance.
   (do this only if you must)

objects that needs a lot of space (i dont remember how much exactly) are saved in Generation One instead Generation Zero. that's why they will remain uncollected for quite some time because GC does not collects Generation One objects often. unless you force it to.